# Process Partial-Respone Query Strings in PHP

Tags: php, regex, api

Prelude: I have done some extensive searching and either found nothing, or wasn't searching for the right thing. Either way I apologize if this is a repeat. Now lets get to the question!

What is the best way to handle partial response query strings in PHP? I mean this in the context of an API. For example with the Facebook API you can request a partial response using the following query string: `...?fields=id,name,albums.limit(10).fields(id,name,description)`

And you'll get a response like this:

```
{
  "id": "000000000", 
  "name": "Hunter Skrasek", 
  "albums": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "58752341440", 
    "name": "Mobile Uploads", 
    "created_time": "2008-12-21T20:08:03+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "189536146440", 
        "name": "Timeline Photos", 
        "created_time": "2009-11-13T04:41:29+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "description": "Where gaming meets the Internet", 
        "id": "10151489643141441", 
        "name": "RTX 2013", 
        "created_time": "2013-07-14T18:20:53+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "10151449802086441", 
        "name": "iPhoto  Photos", 
        "created_time": "2013-06-19T22:57:44+0000"
      },
      ...
    ], 
  }
}
```

I trimmed down the response, but as you can see it translated the fields query into the partial response not only for the main resource but sub-resources as well.

So I am looking for any pointers, or suggestions on how to handle the partial response query string, for both the main resource and sub-resource(s). I was thinking something around splitting on `,`'s first and then from there `.`'s but the problem there is, without Regex the albums.fields(...) content would get split incorrectly. The next thing is figuring out how to store the whole partial response, I had the idea of something like this:

```
array(2) {
  'fields' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(2) "id"
    [1] =>
    string(4) "name"
  }
  'albums' =>
  array(2) {
    'limit' =>
    int(10)
    'fields' =>
    array(3) {
      [0] =>
      string(2) "id"
      [1] =>
      string(4) "name"
      [2] =>
      string(11) "description"
    }
  }
}
```

Alright I think I have provided enough information, but if not I will gladly add more or elaborate on whats already there.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting up the code for the main ressource is simple so far. The query has to be splitted on every `,` if it is not inside a brace:

```
$query = 'id,name,albums.limit(10).fields(id,name,description)';

print_r(parseQuery($query));

function parseQuery($query)
{
  $result = array();
  $lastpos = 0;
  $depth = 0;

  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($query); $i++)
  {
    if ($query[$i] == "," && $depth == 0)
    {
      array_push($result, substr($query, $lastpos, $i - $lastpos));
      $lastpos = $i + 1;
    } else if ($query[$i] == "(")
    {
      $depth++;
    } else if ($query[$i] == ")")
    { 
      $depth--;
    }
  }

  array_push($result, substr($query, $lastpos, $i - $lastpos));

  return $result; // will return Array ( [0] => id [1] => name [2] => albums.limit(10).fields(id,name,description) )
}
```

The next problem is to split up `albums` to subresources. You will have to get the content between `.fields(` and the matching `)`. Then you call the `parseQuery` function recursivly with the extracted string (`id,name,description`).

I hope this helps you a bit!

Comment: I understand the response is JSON, that is not the part I am having trouble with. I am having trouble with turning the query string into the that response. For example without the fields parameter I would get back all the default data for say a "user". But with that fields parameter I am saying, I only want the id and name fields, plus the album sub-resource but only 10 of them with the fields id, name, and description.

Comment: With that query you get the expected response, right? What is the problem with the returned result? Can you explain it once again please, because I still haven't understood the point.

Comment: Ok so say you call a request on to /dogs and you get back:
`id, name, breed, age, owner: {...}`. But you don't need all of that default information on the next request, maybe you want to see if the age has been updated so you request /dogs?fields=age and get back `id, age`. Basically requesting only the fields you want, which is generally called in the API world as Partial Response.

Comment: You mean that the response has more attributes than the request (`id, age` instead of just `age`). If so, what is the problem reading only the `age` index of the result array?

Comment: `id, age` would be appropriate in this instance, because you would always want to respond with the `id` of the object you're working with.

I could just read the `age` or `age, name` from the fields query string, but if I also want to request `age, name, owner.fields(fname,lname)` I am just trying to determine the right way to split up the query string so that I can intelligently determine if I am only returning fields from the main resource, or only certain fields from that resource plus specific fields from a sub-resource.

Comment: Here is another example of what I am trying to do, this is Google's Implementation of what I am talking about: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial

Comment: Ok, now I got the problem! :) Thank you for the explanations. I'm not familiar with the syntax of the query strings, but I will replace my answer by a general approach to this problem. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, and for bearing with me while I tried to explain the question more in-depth. Later today I'll update my original question with the info found here and then start testing out your solution.